# Integer.parseInt and NumberFormatException on Android

Tags: java, android

I ran the following code in my Android app

```
Integer.parseInt("+91");
```

In [Android 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Lollipop) (Lollipop), it ***did not*** throw any exception as `+91` is an integer. But in [Android 4.4.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.4_KitKat_.28API_level_19.29) (KitKat) and lower versions it throws:

> NumberFormatException : Invalid Int : "+91"

How is the version of Android causing this difference?

Comment: Which specific API does this appear in? API-21 or API-22?

Comment: it is a bug. The documentation states the + and - are allowed as plus and minus.. or maybe the documentation is wrong

Comment: Pretty weird, since `parseInt()` is a Java method, not an Android SDK method.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Support for explicit `+` was added in [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/6b40837ee3a023bba698c38fd6d6e46ae0065a55%5E!/):

```
Support explicit + in Byte, Short, Integer, Long.

Bug: 5239391
Change-Id: I2b25228815d70d570d537db0ed9b5b759f25b5a3
```

which has been included starting with `android-5.0.0_r1`. If you have fetched the Git repository, you can verify with:

```
git tag --contains 6b40837ee3a023bba698c38fd6d6e46ae0065a55
```

which gives you

```
android-5.0.0_r1
android-5.0.0_r2
android-5.0.0_r3
...
```

Even though documentation can give insights into *why* the change was made (to achieve Java 7 behavior as other answers point out), analyzing the history of the source code gives the most accurate answer to *when* the behavior changed, since documentation does not necessarily match implementation.

Comment: @MartinNordholts : The commit shows that the change was made in decode(). But parseInt() does not use decode()

Comment: The commit does indeed change `parseInt(String)`, but indirectly. Look at the block labeled `@@ -350,19 +354,17 @@`. That are changes to `Integer.parseInt(String string, int radix)` which is called by `parseInt(String string)`

Comment: @MartinNordholts : Yes, you are right. I think you have given the most correct answer. Android uses it's own implementation of JAVA. There is no point in looking at Oracle Java docs. Can you also please add the above information in your answer?(will help people who are searching for the answer in Oracles docs). Anyway I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 23):

This behaviour is actually part of Java 7, as the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) state:

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters
>   in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first
>   character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a
>   negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a
>   positive value.

*However*, in Java 6 only the `-` symbol was accepted.

The Android SDK 21+ has JDK7 dependencies, which is presumably why you are experiencing this behaviour.

Comment: Android does not use JVM. It uses it's own VM Dalvik Vm for kitkat and below and ART vm for Lollopop and above. So,  I think we should not refere Oracle's documentation here

Comment: @Ashwin Depends. If it claims to be Java, at least the Laguage Specs should be identical. But idk if that also counts for the library calls.

Answer (score 10):

It works after Java 7.

Android 5 introduces the new parseInt feature like the Java 7 version - [Martin Nordholts's answer points exactly the revision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071813/4807777)

So this means that your Lollipop uses a newer sdk based on Java 7  which has the parseInt method with the sign handling part too.

KitKat did introduce [some java 7 features](http://moonlightbox.logdown.com/posts/2015/04/17/android-kitkat-support-java-7) into Android sdk 19, but not the new parseInt. Lower versions use an earlier implementation of parseInt (Java 6's version) so they will obviously fail as well.

---

The difference between parseInt implementations : 
 [Java 6 parseInt documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) vs [Java 7 parseInt documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: The java version has nothing to do with Android API level as far as I know. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: They introduced java 7 features after KitKat http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7

Comment: Cannot find that in the link

Comment: That doesn't talk about java

Comment: That link was cited on a forum discussing the newly introduced support for java 7, indeed it is not in plain java context (java 7 support is mentioned at the end). A clearer link between java 7 and android kitkat :  http://moonlightbox.logdown.com/posts/2015/04/17/android-kitkat-support-java-7 .

Answer (score 5):

This is a Java-specific issue. As you see in the documentation, [Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) allows `-` and [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) allows `+` or `-`.

With Android Version 19 (KitKat) Java 7 is supported, so you don't get this error. I recommend not to use `+`, because you only need a sign if you have a negative integer.

Comment: Android does not use JVM. It uses it's own VM Dalvik Vm for kitkat and below and ART vm for Lollopop and above. So, I think we should not refere Oracle's documentation here

Comment: I agree with that. But Android compile Java-Sourcecode to Java-Bytecode and then to Dalvik-Bytecode (or ART) so the API is pretty much the same. Furthermore I think this explanation is easier than any git diff from the android sourcecode.

Comment: Your explanation is actually wrong. You said "Android Version 19 (KitKat) Java 7 so you don't get this error". BUT I am getting the error in kitkat. Read my question once more "But in KitKat and lower versions ..."

Comment: So, if java 7 allows + and - and kitkat uses Java7, then the error should not have occurred in kitkat. But it did. Because android uses it's own java version.

Comment: Android 19?? The latest version is [5.1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_5.1_Lollipop_.28API_level_22.29) and KitKat is version 4.4 - 4.4.4.

Comment: I refer to the Android API Version